# using scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt

Tags: python, scipy, ipython

I'm trying to get a peak of a noisy frequency spectrum, and it seemed like scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt (documented at [scipy.org](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html)) was a good solution.

However, even after updating scipy, python (and ipython) can't find the function:

```
>>> from scipy.signal import find_peaks_cwt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name find_peaks_cwt
```

Am I importing it wrong? Or is it an unreleased version?
I'm using scipy 0.10.1 on python 2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like its only in the 0.11 version of scipy which you can get from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/)

Comment: Thanks! I installed the latest version off github (0.12.0 dev branch) and it seems to work.